# How do I plot a bunch of points on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I've got a list of hundreds of lat/long coordinates and I want to plot them on Google Maps. What is the easiest way to do this? The data is currently in CSV format.

Comment: A detailed blog: http://sforsuresh.in/display-google-map-locations-using-latitude-longitude/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to create a KML file  with all your lat/long coordinates and open them using Google Earth or Google Maps (http://maps.google.com/maps?q= "YOUR KML FILE URL HERE")

Some info on creating a valid KML file:
http://code.google.com/apis/kml/faq.html#howtocreate

and here you can find an Excel to KML converter:

http://freegeographytools.com/2007/another-excel-to-kml-converter

Comment: "YOUR KML FILE URL" doesn't seem to work at least not with https URL. I tried with this http://maps.google.com/maps?q=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/libkml/master/examples/kml/polygons2d.kml

Comment: Having same issue here as vak, it actually tries to search for the URL, not import it

Comment: It has been a while since I answered this, I think you should take a look at GeoJSON, it is the new standard and it is easy to use or import with lots of map providers (you don't have to use Google with their new expensive price if you don't want to).  Here is an example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-dragndrop

Comment: You should also check out http://geojson.io/ there you have a way to import, export and convert different formats including KML and GeoJSON

Answer (score 9):

This is a 10 second solution to put the points on Google Map - you will need either excel or CSV data which you just copy/paste here: 
http://www.hamstermap.com and then choose Quick Map.

There is also a more complicated map on the website with fancy markers but you will probably need just the quick map.

Comment: unfortunately google maps have stopped supporting the free api version so you can't view the map property anymore

Comment: It would appear that hamster map is defunct now.

Answer (score 9):

One of the simplest way is to copy your coordinates in Excel file.

1. Go to [My Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/).
2. Find/create the map you want the points to appear on.
3. In Excel, export your file as CSV
4. Upload/import the CSV file in My Google Maps.

It will plot all of your points on the map.

Comment: Hi @sonu, welcome to Web Applications! I cleared your post up a bit, hopefully making it a bit easier to read.

Comment: Note: Since the asker already has a CSV file, Excel is not needed :-)

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: Worth pointing out google maps upload allows 2k rows at a time - so if you have a large data set you'll need to break it up into 2k-large layers and upload each one at a time.

Answer (score 4):

[Create a map from a published Google Spreadsheet](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/spreadsheetsmapwizard/makecustommap.htm). The [sample spreadsheet](http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=pnEs2B_37S-DGGFI6kdQZPQ) has lat/long columns.

Comment: link is already dead.

Answer (score 3):

This web tool can do it. It takes a list of comma separated latitude and longitude pairs and puts them on Google Maps. http://www.darrinward.com/lat-long/

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to visualize geographic data out there, but for what you're looking to do, give [this geographic heatmapping tool](http://simpleheatmap.com) a try. Since you've got 100's of data points, a heat map may be better suited to visualizing your data since a bunch of cluttered pins may be hard to read You just need to copy and paste your CSV contents into the textbox, and the service is free. It also supports geocoding smaller datasets if you don't know the coordinates of your locations.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.easymapmaker.com/ enables copy-pasting data directly from excel, AND to include columns other than lat-long and render those to the marker title, label etc so that we can make sense out of what we've plotted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GPS point plotter. Simply copy-paste the lat long list and you will have a map.
https://gpspointplotter.com/

Answer (score 0):

https://www.easymapmaker.com/ enables copy-pasting data directly from excel, AND to include columns other than lat-long and render those to the marker title, label etc so that we can make sense out of what we've plotted.

Answer (score -1):

Try [zeemap](https://www.zeemaps.com/). You can plot your data in csv and import them and then map each field into their pre-defined attributes.

Comment: Always include essential part of the link into answer.